# Tabbar don't appear even content extend below it

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a TabBar view that contain page tabview style, and while content of page is long enough it does not overlap with TabBar and TabBar remain transparent

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            // tab 1
            Text("View 1")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Activities", systemImage: "house")
                }
            // tab 2
            TabView {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text(i.description)
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Activities", systemImage: "gear")
                }
        }
    }
}


struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

I want my content overlap with TabBar when have long content.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve. A paged tab view won’t show a tab bar. You seem to be trying to put a paged tab view (with only one tab/page - the scroll view) inside one of the tabs of a normal tab view.

Comment: please run code in your side, scrollview(paged tabview) have long content but it does not make background of main TabBar appear. in normal case when content of a view long and extended to below of Main TabBar, TabBar transparent go and background appear. so in summery how paged Tabview content can effect main TabBar background appearance.

Comment: Maybe you aren’t supposed to put TabViews inside TabViews?

Comment: i don't have any other choice my app consist of main Tabs (Home, Schedule, Notifications, account) this tabs are using Tabview. and inside schedule i have page TabView to navigate between week days. and here i have problem content of page tabview don't work correctly with main TabBar.

Comment: If you feel you need to put a "TabView" into a "TabView", you need to write a custom one. You can't do that with Apple's `TabView`.